# AWS IoT & Lambda: Triggering function using rule A works but not using rule B

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

Four components are related to this question:

1. The "IoT client": A program that runs in IoT devices, connects to AWS and publishes/subscribes to topics,
2. a Lambda function with two different versions: 1 and 2,
3. an AWS IoT rule (#1) that triggers version 1 of the Lambda function, and
4. an AWS IoT rule (#2) that triggers version 2 of the Lambda function.

Version 2 of the Lambda function introduced breaking changes requiring a new version of the IoT client.

IoT rule #1 uses `$aws/rules/DoSomething/${device_id}`
IoT rule #2 uses `$aws/rules/do_something/${device_id}`

Version 1 of the IoT client uses rule #1 and version 2 of the IoT client uses rule #2. At this point in the IoT client's code, nothing else has changed except changing `DoSomething` to `do_something`.

Using the AWS IoT console, I duplicated rule #2, renamed it to `do_something` instead of `DoSomething` and changed the target to version 2 of the Lambda function instead of version 1.

I have checked the configuration->permissions settings of both versions, and they are identical (allowing writing to the Lambda function's CloudWatch Logs, not version-specific). Both versions are triggered using the same IAM role.

Lambda function v1 has IoT rule #1 as a trigger. Lambda function v1 is also an action of IoT rule #1.
Lambda function v2 has IoT rule #2 as a trigger. Lambda function v2 is also an action of IoT rule #2.

Yet, when the IoT client uses IoT rule #2, the function is never triggered. If I change the rule to IoT rule #1, it triggers the function.

The only thing I need to change to make it trigger some function is `do_something` -> `DoSometing`, but I don't want `DoSomething`, I want `do_something`.

Comparing the two rules in the console, nothing is changed (as far as I can see) except `DoSomething` -> `do_something` and the Lambda function version under *Actions*. The SQL statements are the same.

The two function versions are also identical (as far as I can see) except their code, the version and which rule is hooked up as a trigger.

What did I miss?

Comment: Have you tried publishing a message from within the AWS console to both topics? and subscribe to either topic in the AWS console? Both will help narrow down where the issue is

Comment: An error occurred when subscribing to $aws/rules/do_something/ABC: Connection closed

Answer (score 1):

Check the policy attached to the certificate, which is in turn attached to the thing(device) which is used to publish.

There is a chance that the topic is limited to a certain format like starting with or containing some string.[AWS IoT Core action resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-action-resources.html)

For example, the policy may dictate to have all topics start like
$aws/rules/DoSomething/

You can make use of the MQTT Test client in order to check whether the topic used for publishing is proper, It's available under IOT core itself.[AWS IoT MQTT client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/view-mqtt-messages.html)